# Android Kotlin lint no warning results

Tags: android, kotlin, lint, gradlew

I have a class written in kotlin.
When I right click on the class.kt and press the Analyze->Inspect Code, I do get the kotlin warnings.

If I run from the command line ./gradlew lint, I don t see the class.kt warnings. I do see other warnings, but no Kotlin warnings
Is there anything I m missing from the command line?

I am using Android Sudio 3.1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Kotlin and android lint checks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35590455/kotlin-and-android-lint-checks)

Comment: The answer is, Kotlin checks are not part of the lint plugin yet, but they are building it in. The answer is in the above linked question.

Comment: I see. Thx, If it's build in Android Studio 3.1...how can I run from command line the Analyze->Inspect Code in order to see the warnings/erros results from class.kt ?

Comment: I don't know which to recommend, but do a quick search for a kotlin gradle lint plugin. There are a few options out there. That will add a kotlin lint step to your builds.

Comment: but Analyze->Inspect Code  isn't running inspect.sh? did you try to use this from cmd line

Answer (score 1):

There are two distinct sets of code checks: Android-specific lint checks built by Google, and general Kotlin code inspections built by JetBrains.

Analyze | Inspect Code shows you the results of running both sets of checks: the code inspections are "native" to IntelliJ IDEA, and the Android lint checks have been integrated into IntelliJ IDEA by the Android tools team.

Running `./gradlew lint` runs *only* the Android-specific lint checks. They did add the possibility to handle Kotlin code to these checks in recent versions of Android Studio, but they still check only for Android-specific issues, not general problems with Kotlin code.

If you want to run IntelliJ IDEA's checks from the command line, you can either use `inspect.sh` as described in [IntelliJ IDEA documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/running-inspections-offline.html), or you can use the experimental [Gradle plugin for running IntelliJ IDEA inspections](https://github.com/mglukhikh/inspection-plugin) that JetBrains is working on. Note that the plugin will not run as part of `./gradlew lint`; you'll need to run a separate Gradle task to run its inspections.