# Real time rules with ktlint

Tags: android, kotlin, lint

I am trying to use ktlint on my android project.

Currently I am using these gradle plugins:

```
org.jlleitschuh.gradle.ktlint
org.jlleitschuh.gradle.ktlint-idea
```

I can check the code using a manual gradle task, where the warnings will be displayed by the terminal.

Is it possible to achive something like eslint in javascript? Example:
[image]

Comment: I saw you github comment, so I decided to leave an answer, if you have an issue with following answer let me know.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the following advice does not directly solve your requirement. But, what about making the auto format process part of the build process? I mean, your code will be auto formatted and then checked according to the [ktlint rules](https://ktlint.github.io/#rules) and you only will be worried about to run the build command (i.e. `./gradlew clean build`) before committing your code. This is how I have done that:

First of all, I am using Gradle 6.3 and I have implemented the version 9.1.2 of [org.jlleitschuh.gradle.ktlint](https://github.com/JLLeitschuh/ktlint-gradle) plugin.

Once the plugin has been imported to the project, some tasks are added as the [plugin's documentation](https://github.com/JLLeitschuh/ktlint-gradle#main-tasks) describes:

> This plugin adds two maintasks to every source set: **ktlint[source set name]SourceSetCheck** and **ktlint[source set name]SourceSetFormat**

Usually the added tasks are:

- `ktlintMainSourceSetCheck` and `ktlintMainSourceSetFormat` for `src/kotlin/main` source set
- `ktlintTestSourceSetCheck` and `ktlintTestSourceSetFormat` for `src/kotlin/test` source set

In order to make `ktlintMainSourceSetFormat` and `ktlintTestSourceSetFormat` part of the build process, you should add the following gradle action inside `subprojects { }` section:

For kotlin-based gradle scripts (`build.gradle.kts`):

```
afterEvaluate {
    tasks["ktlintMainSourceSetCheck"].dependsOn(tasks["ktlintMainSourceSetFormat"])
    tasks["ktlintTestSourceSetCheck"].dependsOn(tasks["ktlintTestSourceSetFormat"])
}
```

For groovy-based gradle scripts (`build.gradle`):

```
afterEvaluate {
    tasks.getByName('ktlintMainSourceSetCheck').dependsOn(tasks.getByName('ktlintMainSourceSetFormat'))
    tasks.getByName('ktlintTestSourceSetCheck').dependsOn(tasks.getByName('ktlintTestSourceSetFormat'))
}
```

This makes the "format" tasks mentioned above run before the "check" tasks after the build process of the current sub project has succeeded. These "check" tasks are the ones that display formatting errors in the console whenever the build is run, but making them children of the "format" tasks will force the build process to format the code before checking it so that no formatting errors will show up in the console.

Additionally, you can also apply code checks and formats to build script files (`build.gradle(.kts)`) by adding the following code inside `allprojects { }` section:

```
afterEvaluate {
    tasks["ktlintKotlinScriptCheck"].dependsOn(tasks["ktlintKotlinScriptFormat"])
}
```

**For Git support:**

If you want to add the auto formatting feature at pre-commit stage, you can use these tasks: `addKtlintCheckGitPreCommitHook` and `addKtlintFormatGitPreCommitHook` as explained [here](https://github.com/JLLeitschuh/ktlint-gradle#additional-helper-tasks)

**For IntelliJ IDEA support:**

If you want to apply the [ktlint rules](https://ktlint.github.io/#rules) to your current project, just execute the following gradle command once you have imported the `org.jlleitschuh.gradle.ktlint-idea` plugin: `./gradlew ktlintApplyToIdea` and this will replace the `codeStyles` file inside `.idea/` folder as described [here](https://github.com/JLLeitschuh/ktlint-gradle#additional-helper-tasks)

Finally, [here](https://github.com/jcflorezr/audio-splitter/blob/feature/implementing-ddd/build.gradle.kts) is an example of a `build.gradle.kts` where all the mentioned above is applied.

Comment: "If you want to add the auto formatting feature at pre-commit stage" You cannot add both right? At least I tested it and both overwrite the same file.

Answer (score 0):

You will not get an error message like in eslint but using following method you won't need to deal with ktlint styling issues manually. Is not it much better than manually fixing things up?

1. Install ktlint commandline tools as described [here](https://github.com/pinterest/ktlint#installation).
2. Set IntelliJ IDEA's code styles to align with ktlint's code styles as described [here](https://github.com/pinterest/ktlint#option-2).

So when you make a commit using IntelliJ IDEA's commit window (<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> or <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>) and you have reformat code before commit enabled then your commit will be made with correct code styles.

Comment: Its okay, but the answer is if its possible to see the warnings more friendly like eslint, directly on the IDE, instead in the console

Comment: with this method you will not see warnings in the console, since on commit all code is properly formatted. Is not it cool than to manually fix things after seeing a warning?

Comment: Do you still see warnings in terminal when you ran ./gradlew ktlint? If so let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install plugin [Ktlint ​(unofficial)​](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/15057-ktlint-unofficial-) and follow setup instructions.

Go to `Preferences > Tools > ktlint` and make sure `Enabled ktlint` checkbox is selected.

In case of android project also select `Android mode` check box.